# How to use scanf("%[^\n]s")?

Tags: c

```
void ScanfTest()
{
    char c[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]s", c);
        printf("%s\n", c);
    }
}
```

I want this code to repeat input and output 10 times.

Why is "hi im newb" printed 10 times when I type "hi im newb" in this code?

And if you change the scanf() part to gets(), it works normally.
What is the difference between scanf("%[^\n]s") and gets()?

Comment: Do you understand that nul-terminated strings in C require an actual character to store that terminator? Otherwise there's no way to know where the string ends. You allocated only 10 bytes for the string, but it needs 11. This entire thing is crazy unsafe. Use `fgets`.

Comment: The format you "want" — if you really want to try to use `scanf` in this way — is `" %[^\n]"`, not `"%[^\n]s"`.   Note the extra space, and the deleted `s`. (But IMO, `%[…]` is more trouble that it's worth, and you're better off using `fgets`.)

Comment: Never use something like `char c[10];` to read a string.  Always make it bigger — comfortably bigger — than you'll ever need.  I'd go with `char c[100];`, or `char c[512];`, or even `char c[1024];`.

Comment: Always check the return value of functions that can fail and you can handle it, such as `scanf()`. Don't use `scanf()` with `%s` without limiting the maximum length, otherwise it is as bad as `gets()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%[^\n]", c);
```

will read a string of non-newline characters into c, stopping at (and not reading) the first newline.  That newline will remain in stdin for the next call, so repeating this will fail to read anything (as there are no non-newline characters before the next newline still waiting to be read).  You should check the return value of `scanf` to see if the pattern matched or not.

```
gets(c);
```

will read characters up to (and including) the next newline, and that newline will then be discarded.

Both examples will overrun the buffer if too many characters are entered (as you are doing), so should never be used.  Use `fgets` or `scanf("%9[^\n]", c)` instead.

The spurious `s` in the format in your original code will never match (after the `%[^\n]`, the next character will always be a newline, never an `s`, unless EOF is reached, which also isn't an `s`)

---

The most common way to deal with the newline if you want to use scanf like this is to put a space in the beginning of the format to discard any left-over whitespace from a previous call.  For example

```
if (scanf(" %9[^\n]", c) <= 0) {
    /* failed to read data (due to EOF or I/O error) */
} else {
    /* successfuly read something into 'c' */
}
```

this will also ignore any leading whitespace on the line, as well as any other blank lines.

If you're on a POSIX system, you can let it allocate memory for you to deal with larger strings:

```
char *c;
if (scanf(" %m[^\n]", &c) == 1) {
    /* read a string into c, so do something with it */
    free(c);
} else {
    /* there was a problem */
}
```